# Ajax request doubled, tripled or multiplied n-times because of dynamically loaded content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

I'm facing a problem and I can't figure out how to solve. Multiple days trying to search on Google for the right answer, but yet no solution.

I am using Bootstrap 4 and loading modal with an ajax request based on an ID.
In this Modal there's also a [Add] button, to add more rows to the table of thats specific ID. This works perfectly fine.

Within that table I would like to add a [remove]-button and when clicked, there should be another ajax request triggered for removing that row, without reloading the page. But because the DOM already loaded, the secondary loaded content will not use the jquery-file. So no actions are triggered.
I tried to add the .js-file into the dynamically loaded content, but when I use the [add]-function above, the action will be fired double and when I delete 2 rows, the add function will be triggered 6 times, and so on.

How can I add a JS-file properly so that the functions I wrote in the JS-file will be executed once and will work.

I have some code to understand the logic I use(d):

This is the code I use to load a Modal, based on an ID.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.view_datainDelen').click(function() {
        var uitgaveid = $(this).attr("id");
        getBetaalInDeleninfo(uitgaveid);
    });
    
});
        
function getBetaalInDeleninfo(uitgaveid) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'dynamicData/GetBetalingInfo.php?type=betaalindeleninfo',
        method:"post",
        data:{rowid:uitgaveid},
        success:function(data){
            $('#BetaalInDelenInfo').html(data);
            $('#BetaalInDelenModal').modal("show");
            getBetalingInDelenTabel(uitgaveid);
        }
    });
}
```

When the modal pops up, a PHP file will be executed and return the outcome of a database-query in a table. In this file is also the JS included.
After adding or removing rows to this table I call function to reload the table with the new content. This works fine, but after loading this page, the remove button won't work.

```
if(isset($_GET['uitgaveid']) && is_numeric($_GET['uitgaveid'])) {
            $uitgaveid = tekst($_GET['uitgaveid']);
            
            //Table met deelbetalingen
            $qDeelbetalingen = $mysqli->query(" ##Query not important for the purpose of this question                      
                                            ");
                                                    
                    $totaalbedrag = 0;
                    $output = '';
                    while($db = $qDeelbetalingen->fetch_assoc()) {
                        
                        $output .= '
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>'.$db['betaaldOp'].'</td>
                                        <td class="text-right text-nowrap">'.euro($db['bedrag']).'</td>
                                        <td class="text-right text-nowrap">
                                            <button class="btn btn-link btn-sm submit_verwijderdeelbetaling" id="'.$db['uitgavedeelbetalingid'].'">
                                                <span class="fas fa-trash fa-fw"></span>
                                            </button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    ';
                                        
                        $totaalbedrag = $totaalbedrag + $db['bedrag'];
                    }
                    $output .= '
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><strong>Totaal:</strong></td>
                                        <td class="text-right text-nowrap"><strong>'.euro($totaalbedrag).'</strong></td>
                                        
                                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    ';
                                        
                    echo $output;
                    
        } else {
            echo 'Ongeldige ID';
        }
```

So I added the js-file and tried to delete the JS-file when the ajax is succesfully loaded and then load the js-file on completion:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.view_datainDelen').click(function() {
        var uitgaveid = $(this).attr("id");
        getBetaalInDeleninfo(uitgaveid);
    });
    
    $('.submit_verwijderdeelbetaling').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        
        var uitgavedeelbetalingid   = $(this).attr('id');
        var uitgaveid               = $("#uitgaveid").val();
        VerwijderBetaalInDelen(uitgaveid, uitgavedeelbetalingid);
    });
    
    $('#submit_deelbetaling').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        
        var uitgaveid   = $("#uitgaveid").val();
        var betaaldOp   = $("#betaaldOp").val();
        var bedrag      = $("#bedrag").val();
        
        NieuwBetaalInDelen(uitgaveid, betaaldOp, bedrag);
            
    });
    
});

function VerwijderBetaalInDelen(uitgaveid, uitgavedeelbetalingid) {
    $.ajax({
        type:   'post',
        url:    'DataHandlers/administratiedeelbetaling.handler.php?type=verwijder',
        data: { formulier: 'VerwijderDeelbetaling',
                uitgaveid: uitgaveid,
                uitgavedeelbetalingid: uitgavedeelbetalingid
            },
        success: function(html){
                getBetalingInDelenTabel(uitgaveid);
                
                $("script[src='/js/deelbetalingen.js']").remove()
            },
        complete: function() {
                $.getScript("/js/deelbetalingen.js", function() {});
            }
        
        
    });
}

function NieuwBetaalInDelen(uitgaveid, betaaldOp, bedrag) {
    $.ajax({
        type:   'post',
        url:    'DataHandlers/administratiedeelbetaling.handler.php?type=nieuw',
        data: { formulier: 'deelbetaling',
                uitgaveid: uitgaveid,
                betaaldOp: betaaldOp,
                bedrag: bedrag
            },
        success: function(html){
                getBetalingInDelenTabel(uitgaveid);
                
                $("script[src='/js/deelbetalingen.js']").remove()
            },
        complete: function() {
                $.getScript("/js/deelbetalingen.js", function() {});
            }
    });
}
```

I've tried to change the place of including the files.
Make a function so I can call the function.

I hope someone can give me the right way to load js-files into double dynamically loaded content.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you create the same event handler over and over again. A trick that you can do in order to only once create such an event handler is to have an `initialize` class which you add to anything whose event you are setting up and you worry about duplicating it and to add the event handler if and only if the `initialized` class was not added yet. In the snippet below I call `initialize()` thrice and you see that the event is being created only once. If you understand this trick, then you can consistently apply to your event handler creation.

```js
function initialize() {
    $(".btn:not(.initialized)").click(function() {
        alert(this.value);
    }).addClass("initialized");
}

initialize();
initialize();
initialize();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="btn" value="click me one">
<input type="button" class="btn" value="click me too">
<input type="button" class="btn" value="click me three">
```

Comment: Thanks, I’m going to try your solution

Comment: @nathanael happy to help! Please let me know of your results.